# Input text color change is not proper with addEventListener

Tags: javascript

From the input element Id 'email', I am performing an `addEventListener` operation for dynamic email validation. The color of text will be **'black'** if it is **valid** or **'maroon'** if it's **not**.

```
<!-- HTML -->    
<input type="text" id="email" name="email">

//Javascript
document.getElementById('email').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
            var value = this.value;
            ValidateEmail(value);

            function ValidateEmail(mail)   {
                if (/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(mail))
                {
                    console.log("ok");
                    var red = document.getElementById('email');
                    red.style.color = 'black';
                    return (true);
                } else {
                    console.log("You have entered an invalid email address!");
                    var red = document.getElementById('email');
                    red.style.color = '#9e1e1e';
                    return (false);
                }
            }
        });
```

The above program is working but with one issue, ie. the function validates the text only on the next `'keydown' event`.

Ex. `'smith@email.co'` is a valid email string, but the color changes only on the next event operation (which is `'smith@email.com'` or `'smith@email.c'`).

Comment: use `keyup` instead

Comment: you want to validate after entry is done ???when loose focus

Comment: @gurvinder372 thank you. it's working.

Comment: @PranayRana in that case the OP could use `blur`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - thats what need to be done i guess ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `keyup` instead of `keydown`.

**Why?**

Because when you use `keydown`, the event is fired and your function is run before the new character is inserted into the `<input>` field. So that the function gets the old value and validate incorrectly.

When you use `keyup`, the event is fired and your function is run after the new character is inserted into the `<input>` field so that your function and get the value correctly and validate it correctly.

```js
document.getElementById('email').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
            var value = this.value;
            ValidateEmail(value);

            function ValidateEmail(mail)   {
                if (/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(mail))
                {
                    console.log("ok");
                    var red = document.getElementById('email');
                    red.style.color = 'black';
                    return (true);
                } else {
                    console.log("You have entered an invalid email address!");
                    var red = document.getElementById('email');
                    red.style.color = '#9e1e1e';
                    return (false);
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="email" name="email">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `keydown` event fires when the key is pressed, but before the value has been updated. This can be excellent as it lets you cancel the change in value that the keypress would normally trigger if it is a "bad" key, but it doesn't help solve your problem.

Use [the `input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) instead of the `keypress` event. This will fire after the value has changed, even if it was changed by using the mouse to paste a new value into the field.